# HTML and CSS: how to center two inline form buttons?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I'm brand new to HTML and CSS.  I'm trying to center two form buttons.  Here is my code:

```css
* {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: column;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border: 1px solid #f8f9fa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 11px 4px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  line-height: 27px;
  height: 36px;
  min-width: 54px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.search_area {
  display: flex;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.search_box {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Google</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="google.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <a href="images.html">Image Search</a>
    <a href="advanced.html">Advanced Search</a>
  </nav>

  <form class="search" action="https://www.google.com/search">
    <img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Google logo">
    <div>
      <input name="q" type="text" class="search_area">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Search Google" class="buttons">
    <input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" class="buttons">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the two buttons beneath the search bar are justified to the left.  I thought that `text-align: center` is the solution.  But, this doesn't seem to work.

How do I get these two buttons to center on the screen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A sample update:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
                        <title>Google</title>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="google.css">
                    </head>

                    <body>
                        <nav>
                            <a href="images.html">Image Search</a>
                            <a href="advanced.html">Advanced Search</a>
                        </nav>

                        <form class="search" action="https://www.google.com/search">
                            <div style="
                "><img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Google logo" style=""></div>
                    <div style="">
                            <div style="display: flex;align-content: center;">
                                <input name="q" type="text" class="search_area">
                            </div>
                    <div style="">
                                <input type="submit" value="Search Google" class="buttons">
                                <input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" class="buttons">               
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                    
                </body></html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
                    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                }

                body {
                    /*display: flex;
                    align-items: column;*/
                }

                .buttons {
                    background-color: #f8f9fa;
                    border: 1px solid #f8f9fa;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    margin: 11px 4px;
                    padding: 0 16px;
                    line-height: 27px;
                    height: 36px;
                    min-width: 54px;
                    text-align: center;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    user-select: none;
                    display: inline-block;
                }


                .search_area {
                    display: flex;
                    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
                    border: 1px solid #ddd;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 34px;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    border-radius: 25px;
                }

                nav {
                    display: flex;
                    margin-right: 30px;
                    margin-top: 15px;
                }

                form{
                    display: table;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                }

                .search_box {
                    text-align: center;
                    display: block;
                }
```

Comment: A good answer does not just rely on code. You should explain what you have done differently and how it addresses the problem. Use comments in the code to highlight changes

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS code:

Just paste it and see the changes.

I have commented the body section and it worked.

```
*{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
    /*display: flex;
    align-items: column;*/  /*I have commented the body CSS lines*/
}

.buttons {
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border: 1px solid #f8f9fa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 11px 4px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    line-height: 27px;
    height: 36px;
    min-width: 54px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    display: inline-block;
}


.search_area {
    display: flex;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

form{
    display: table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.search_box {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: A good answer does not just rely on code. You should explain what you have done differently and how it addresses the problem. Use comments in the code to highlight changes

Answer (score 0):

In your body tags don't use **display: flex** because when you used display flex then **text-align: center** wouldn't work. In your **form** tag you have a  **.search** class. for centerizing i used   **.search { margin: 0 auto; width: 50%}**

This is HTML code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Google</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="google.css">
    
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <nav>
                <a href="images.html">Image Search</a>
                <a href="advanced.html">Advanced Search</a>
            </nav>
    
            <form class="search" action="https://www.google.com/search">
                <img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Google logo">
                <div>
                    <input name="q" type="text" class="search_area">
                </div>
    
                <div class="button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search Google" class="buttons">
                    <input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" class="buttons">         
                </div>      
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And here is Css:

```
*{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

/* body{display: flex;align-items: column;}  */

.buttons {
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border: 1px solid #f8f9fa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 11px 4px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    line-height: 27px;
    height: 36px;
    min-width: 54px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.button{
    text-align: center;
}


.search_area {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.search{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.search_box {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```